# Codeigniter Dynamic Routing from database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have implemented a dynamic routing system to my Codeigniter from the database. while am loading the routes dynamically it is showing me an internal server error 500. I have already implemented in my other projects also but it's not possible here. I am using Codeigniter https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

```
// $route['default_controller'] = 'Home';
// $route['person/(:any)'] = 'Home/person_data/$1';
// $route['filmography/(:any)'] = 'Home/filmo_details/$1';
// $route['biography/(:any)'] = 'Home/bio_details/$1';
// $route['article/(:any)'] = 'Home/article_details/$1';
// $route['jukebox/(:any)'] = 'Home/jukebox/_details/$1';
// $route['admin'] = 'Admin';
// $route['login'] = 'Admin/login';
// $route['404_override'] = '';
// $route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;

$route[ 'default_controller' ]  = 'Home';
$route['admin'] = 'Admin';
$route['login'] = 'Admin/login';
$route[ '404_override' ]        = 'my404';

require_once(BASEPATH .'database/DB'. EXT);
$db =& DB();
$query = $db->get( '_app_routes' );
$result = $query->result();
// echo"<pre>";print_r($result);exit;
foreach( $result as $row )
{
    $route[ $row->slug ]                 = $row->controller;
    $route[ $row->slug.'/:any' ]         = $row->controller;
    $route[ $row->controller ]           = $row->controller;
    $route[ $row->controller.'/:any' ]   = $row->controller;
}
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;



/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sample REST API Routes
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
$route['api/example/users/(:num)'] = 'api/example/users/id/$1'; // Example 4
$route['api/example/users/(:num)(\.)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(.*)'] = 'api/example/users/id/$1/format/$3$4'; // Example 8
```

**Controller**

```
public function person_details($personid){
        $data = array();
        $data['persondata']=$this->User_model->getPersondata($personid);
        // echo"<pre>";print_r($data);exit;
        $this->load->view('default/person_details_view',$data);
    }
```

**Routes generated**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [slug] => pawan-kalyan
            [controller] => Home/person_details/1
            [PAGE_ID] => 1
            [PAGE_GROUP_ID] => 1
            [STATUS] => 1001
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [slug] => chiranjeevi
            [controller] => Home/person_details/2
            [PAGE_ID] => 2
            [PAGE_GROUP_ID] => 1
            [STATUS] => 1001
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 3
            [slug] => nagababu
            [controller] => Home/person_details/3
            [PAGE_ID] => 3
            [PAGE_GROUP_ID] => 1
            [STATUS] => 1001
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 4
            [slug] => allu-arjun
            [controller] => Home/person_details/4
            [PAGE_ID] => 4
            [PAGE_GROUP_ID] => 1
            [STATUS] => 1001
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 5
            [slug] => ram-charan-tej
            [controller] => Home/person_details/5
            [PAGE_ID] => 5
            [PAGE_GROUP_ID] => 1
            [STATUS] => 1001
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 6
            [slug] => sai-dharam-tej
            [controller] => Home/person_details/6
            [PAGE_ID] => 6
            [PAGE_GROUP_ID] => 1
            [STATUS] => 1001
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 7
            [slug] => varun-tej
            [controller] => Home/person_details/7
            [PAGE_ID] => 7
            [PAGE_GROUP_ID] => 1
            [STATUS] => 1001
        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 8
            [slug] => naga-babu-says-i-don't-know-balakrishna
            [controller] => Home/article_details/1
            [PAGE_ID] => 8
            [PAGE_GROUP_ID] => 1
            [STATUS] => 1001
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed the bracket for the `regexp` match. i.e the `:any` should be like `(:any)`. Update the route like below and try.

```
foreach( $result as $row )
{
    $route[ $row->slug ]                 = $row->controller;
    $route[ $row->slug.'/(:any)' ]         = $row->controller;
    $route[ $row->controller ]           = $row->controller;
    $route[ $row->controller.'/(:any)' ]   = $row->controller;
}
```

Comment: Now am getting the routes, but when I use them it's showing 404 and it is not redirecting to the page @Saji

Comment: @SairamDuggi can you show  1 or 2 routes created dynamically?

Comment: Updated the question, please check

Comment: Can you make the controller name lower `strtolower($row->controller);` and try

Comment: no not working, for a project which is in production is working perfectly with the same code

Comment: Vhich version of codeigniter you use? And the controller class and name uses first letter capital? Are you sure the `.htaccess` is there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190585/discussion-between-saji-and-sairam-duggi).